# Non editable cell in qtableview

Tags: pyside, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a QTableView for a custom class inherited from QAbstractTableModel.

Does someone knows a way to set a particular cell of a QTableView (or the model) as non editable according to a value from another cell of the same row of the model?

Im using PySide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `flags` [method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) of the model and make sure that the `ItemIsEditable` is not included in the results.

For instance include this in your model class:

```
def flags(self, index):
    """ Returns the item flags for the given index.
    """
    return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping not do something like this. The model is dynamic. Its constantly growing (in rows), so keeping track of the related indexes is going to be a problem. But it seems that I have no other alternative.